# For the below code it should show 01/01/currentyear in startdate and in enddate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For the above requirement, we need to show 01/01/current-Year in the start date input field and in the end-date input field it should display the current day date. This condition is satisfied for the below code.

Currently, it is allowing me to take the dates irrespective of the year but while submitting the button it is again taking on the current year dates with the below code.

```js
//current month and year
var yearNow = new Date().getFullYear();
var monthNow = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

//set the start date's field value to current year
document.getElementById('date-start').value = "01/01/" + yearNow;

//set the value of the end date field to current date
document.getElementById('date-end').value = monthNow + "/" + new Date().getDate() + "/" + yearNow;
```

```html
<label for="date-start">Start Date</label>
<input class="date-picker" id="date-start">
<label for="end-date">End Date</label>
<input class="date-picker" id="date-end">
```

Key Note: For the above code it should show 01/01/currentyear in startdate and in enddate it should display the current day date but when we select different dates also it should work after submitting the button also.

By default, it should display 01/01/currentyear in startdate and in enddate it should display the current day date

for the datetime-local it is taking 6 digits for the year it should only 4 digits for year

Comment: Aside from the question, buttons are not submitted, forms are. Setting the start date to readonly might help for your issue?

Comment: To the labels you are adding the static values which are not taken from the date selector. To Update it dynamically you need to read the input from the date picker you may: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Your *provided* code appears to work correctly and you state this with "*This condition is satisfied for the below code*" - so what doesn't this code do that you can *demonstrate*?   There's no submit button in your code (or even a `form`); where does it submit to?  Please update your snippet to *demonstrate* the issue.

Comment: the data is coming from the backend but in the frontend, we need to give the option to users to select the dates as they expected